# RadDataForm nativescript vue show/hide password

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Have this part of code form:

```
<RadDataForm id="loginForm" ref="loginForm" :source="user">
  <TKEntityProperty v-tkDataFormProperty name="password" displayName imageResource="res://lock" hintText="Password" index="0">
    <TKPropertyEditor v-tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Password">
      <TKPropertyEditorStyle v-tkPropertyEditorStyle labelWidth="4" />
    </TKPropertyEditor>
  </TKEntityProperty>
</RadDataForm>
```

Need to append icon/image can tap to show/hide password

Comment: I think it would be easier if you introduce a custom editor for this purpose, may be a TextField and Image wrapped with GridLayout.

Comment: Can explane a structure for nativescript-vue with custom editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, [CustomPropertyEditor](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/DataForm/Editors/dataform-editors-custom#raddataform-custom-editors) is not yet exposed as Vue directive in latest version of nativescript-ui-dataform plugin (as of today v4.0.0).

So you will have to register it first along with RadDataForm, may be something like

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import * as RadDataFormModule from "nativescript-ui-dataform";

import RadDataForm from "nativescript-ui-dataform/vue";
Vue.use(RadDataForm);

Vue.registerElement("TKCustomPropertyEditor", function () {
    return RadDataFormModule.CustomPropertyEditor;
});
```

Now simply use `TKCustomPropertyEditor` instead of `TKPropertyEditor`

```
        <TKEntityProperty v-tkDataFormProperty name="password">
            <TKCustomPropertyEditor v-tkEntityPropertyEditor
                @editorNeedsView="onPasswordEditorNeedsView">
            </TKCustomPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
```

Now you can create and assign the view you like on the `editorNeedsView` event as described in the docs.